# Binding collection from wcf response to a dropdownlist

Tags: wcf, data-binding, serialization

I've a wcf service which returns a generic list : List lstAccount.
The presentation layer client in my winforms app is using proxy object to connect to this service.

In the proxy, Account class gets generated like this:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.Common")]
    public partial class Account {}
```

When I bind this lstAccount to a dropdownlist on the form in my presentation layer[by setting the datasource property],the dropdownlist just shows the class name "Account" instead of shwoing account name.

```
this.cblExistingAccounts.DataSource = lstAccount;
this.cblExistingAccounts.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

What am i missing over here?

Thanks.

Comment: When you test the webmethod in wcftestclient do you get the records? The client should call the  proxy method first which I don't see here...

Comment: Yes,i do get records from the service.For brevity,I didnt add that code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the properties of the account class on the service side are decorated with the DataMember attribute.

EDIT: Make sure that your proxy is up to date as well, try refreshing it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I dont have svcUtil utility.I've DatasvcUtil.exe file on my machine.Can I use that instead to generate the proxy?

Comment: If you created the proxy using the Visual Studio "Service Reference" feature, you can right-click on it and select "Update Service Reference"

Comment: I added DataMember attribute on the server side, generated the proy again, but same result.May I know what difference would appear in proxy object after adding this attribute?Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Johann for ur inputs.I now added both DataContract and DataMember attributes on the server side and it is working now.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the binding like:

```
this.cblExistingAccounts.DataSource = lstAccount;
this.cblExistingAccounts.DataTextField = "Name";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but am using System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox with this.cblExistingAccounts.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;It does not have DataTextField  property.